# Machine Learning Loss Functions In C++

Tags: c++, performance, machine-learning

I was looking for C++ versions of the machine learning metrics implemented in Python's sklearn, but they were surprisingly hard to find. I came across [a website that had most of the loss functions implemented in Python](https://cppsecrets.com/user/index.php?id=articles&uid=5758), so I did my best to translate them to C++.

Below is what I have so far. I plan to implement most of the metrics on that page.

From testing, I'm not really getting the speed I was expecting.

Two notes:

1. I've found that object members having their own local variables, rather than having to access shared class variables, gives a small speed boost. That's why several functions have their own similar variables that I decided not to make class members.
2. I also found that using my own squaring function is faster than `std::pow(n, 2)`.

```
// metrics.hpp

#include <vector>
#include <cmath>




class Metrics {
    
    // utils
    
    double square (double res) {
        
        return res * res ;
    
    }
    

    public:
        
        // regression
    
    
        double mean_absolute_error (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                store += std::abs(y_true[i] - y_pred[i]) ;
                
                }
            
            return store/size ;
                
            }
        
        
        double root_mean_square_error (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                store += square((y_true[i] - y_pred[i])) ;
                
                }
            
            return std::sqrt(store / size) ;    
            
            }
            
        
        double mean_gamma_deviance (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                store += 2.0 * (std::log(y_pred[i]/y_true[i]) + (y_true[i]/y_pred[i]) - 1.0) ;
                
                }
            
            return store / size ;    
            
            }
            
        
        double mean_poisson_deviance (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                store += 2.0 * ((y_true[i]*std::log(y_true[i]/y_pred[i])) + (y_pred[i]-y_true[i])) ;
                
                }
            
            return store / size ;    
            
            }
            
        
        // classification
        
        
        double accuracy (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i]){
                    
                    store += 1.0 ;
                    
                    }
                
                }
            
            return -(store / size) ;
                
            }
        
        
        double precision (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred
        ) {
            
            double tp {0} ; // true positive
            double fp {0} ; // false positive
            
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i] == 1) {
                    
                    tp += 1.0 ;
                    
                    }
                }
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] != y_pred[i] && y_pred[i]==1) {
                    
                    fp += 1.0 ;
                    
                    
                    }
                }
            
            return tp/(tp+fp) ;
                
                
                }
        
        
        double recall (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred
        ) {
           
            double tp {0} ; // true positive
            double fn {0} ; // false negative
            
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i] == 1) {
                    
                    tp += 1.0 ;
                    
                    }
                }
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] != y_pred[i] && y_pred[i] == 0) {
                    
                    fn += 1.0 ;
                
                    }
                }
            
            return tp/(tp+fn) ;
            
        }
            
            
        double f1 (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double prec {precision(y_true, y_pred)} ;
            
            double rec {recall(y_true, y_pred)}  ;
                
            return -(2 * ((prec*rec) / (prec+rec))) ;
            
            }
    
    
        double jaccard_score (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double intersect {0} ;
            double uni {0} ;
            
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i]) {
                    
                    intersect += 1.0 ;
                    
                    }
                }
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                    uni += 1.0 ;
                    
                }
            
            return intersect / uni ;
                
                    }


} met ;
```

Comment: The biggest reason why you don't get good speed is because you're not exactly using the right tools. You should look into CUDA programming or at least use a library like Eigen to benefit from hardware optimization and parallelism :)

Comment: `y_pred[i] == 1`, `y_pred[i] == 0)` - are you sure `y_pred[]` is really `double`?

Comment: @vnp Yes, my data and model predictions are all double. Obviously that can be changed if someone wants to use these methods with different types.

Comment: @craftycroft, could you please also post your benchmarks? I believe those as important as the code being benchmarked. Collecting performance metrics correctly is an art on its own. Did you compile with optimizations? Could you please also provide python code to compare against.

Comment: I may write a review later (it usually takes me a few days because I write long reviews). However, as a quickie suggestion… are you sure you’re actually profiling optimized code? [GCC optimizes `std::pow(x, 2);` to `mulsd %xmm0, %xmm0` even at `-O1`](https://godbolt.org/z/9vb7x8rx7). Frankly the level of micro-optimizing you’re doing is ridiculous with modern compilers. *Are* you using a modern compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Design review

There are two very common mistakes people make when trying to translate code from other languages to C++ looking for a performance boost.

The first is trying a direct translation: that is, literally rewriting the exact same code logic from the other language to C++. There are *countless* posts on StackOverflow from people who rewrote some code from another language in C++, and are baffled why they aren’t getting a massive speed improvement. The reason for that should be obvious; if you just do the exact same thing in C++ that you did in Python or Java or whatever… what else would you expect to happen? C++ isn’t magical. It will take your CPU the same time to add, multiply, and do all the other operations regardless of the language you specified those operations in. If you do the same operations, you’ll get roughly the same performance.

Each programming language has its own philosophy. When I write Python, I *think* very differently than when I write C++. If you want to get the most out of C++, you need to align your thinking with the philosophy of C++. You need to do things the C++ way. You need to learn and use the language’s idioms. Good code looks *very* different in C++ than it does in Python, even when that code is supposed to be doing the same thing.

That being said…

Sometimes—quite often, in fact—you *will* get a performance boost from a simple direct translation to C++. Maybe not as much as you were hoping for, but the exact same algorithm *usually* runs at least a little bit faster when implemented in C++. And the reason for that is: the compiler.

Which brings us to the second common mistake people trying to translate code to C++ for a performance boost make: thinking that it’s all about the language.

C++, more so than perhaps any other popular language, ***DEPENDS*** on the compiler. That’s the true secret to its power and efficiency; C++ is designed, from the ground up, to work ***WITH*** the compiler—hand-in-hand, as a partnership. C++ without a compiler is… nothing; it’s actually a pretty shitty language, on its own. So if you’re just looking at the code—the language—without taking into account what the compiler can, should, and probably will do for you, you’re just not going to get the promised performance benefits of C++.

So if you have an algorithm or tool implemented in another language, and you want better performance, you can *always*† get it with C++… but you need to do two things:

1. You need to completely rethink, redesign, and rewrite the code, starting from scratch, using C++ philosophy.
2. You need to work *with* the compiler. Don’t think of it just as a tool. In C++, the compiler is your partner in performance.

(† There is no qualifier there; it is *always* possible, at least in theory, to get equivalent *or better* performance if you rewrite something in C++ *properly*. Yes, [C++ can even beat C](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/rants/c++-vs-c/).)

So let’s look at your code, keeping those two common mistakes in mind.

So the original Python code put everything in classes for… reasons?  A direct translation of [the precision score code](https://cppsecrets.com/users/575811210512111711510410010510711510410511657575764103109971051084699111109/Python-Scikit-Learn-Precision-Score.php) would look something like this:

```
class Precision
{
    std::size_t tp = 0;
    std::size_t fp = 0;

public:
    auto true_positive(std::vector<double> const& l1, std::vector<double> const& l2)
    {
        for (auto i : std::views::iota(decltype(l1.size()){}, l1.size()))
        {
            if (l1[i] == l2[i] and l2[i] == 1) // *
                tp += 1;
        }

        // *:   Note that Python promises that l2[i] is only evaluated once,
        //      while C++ does not. However, even the most half-assed C++
        //      compiler will optimize it to a single load.
    }

    auto false_positive(std::vector<double> const& l1, std::vector<double> const& l2)
    {
        for (auto i : std::views::iota(decltype(l1.size()){}, l1.size()))
        {
            if (l1[i] != l2[i] and l2[i] == 1)
                fp += 1;
        }
    }

    auto calc_precision(std::vector<double> const& l1, std::vector<double> const& l2)
    {
        true_positive(l1, l2);
        false_positive(l1, l2);

        std::cout << (tp / double(tp + fp));
    }
};
```

However, that’s *horrible* C++.

Your version of the precision score code is essentially just that, with `true_positive()` and `false_positive()` inlined, and the member variables `tp` and `fp` turned into local variables (and, of course, you return the value instead of printing it). That’s a *slight* improvement—some bugs are fixed, some new bugs are introduced, but overall it’s a bit better. However, it’s still not what you’d write if you were actually trying to solve this problem in C++.

Additionally, the “fixes” you made—like moving the member variables to be locals, creating your own `square()` function, and so on—are mostly micro-optimizations attempting to “outsmart” or work around the compiler. But the compiler is a ***LOT*** smarter than you give it credit for. I dare say: the compiler is smarter than you are. I don’t say that to imply you’re not smart: in point of fact, I know the compiler is smarter than I am, too.

Let’s consider the squaring issue. You claim that manually squaring via `x * x` is faster than `std::pow(x, 2)`. I call bullshit. I mentioned in a comment that [GCC optimizes `std::pow(x, 2)` to a single multiply instruction even at optimization level 1](https://godbolt.org/z/9vb7x8rx7), but I also offer [this Quick Bench comparison (which uses Clang, just for variation) that shows *exactly* the same performance either way](https://quick-bench.com/q/jTITYv4mPxGECAU03Lmdo_cVJlo).

But let’s dig deeper. Let’s try *cubing*. [Aha! Now we see that GCC *doesn’t* replace the call to `std::pow(x, 3)`](https://godbolt.org/z/E1bh4M9Wf)! Have we finally outsmarted the compiler?

Nope. In fact, the compiler has *way* outsmarted both of us.

See, what’s happening here is super-complex, and goes deep into the weeds of how numbers and calculations work in a computer, IEEE 754 crap, and so on. But the very, very basic explanation is that the compiler can always transform `pow(x, 2)` into a single multiply instruction because the multiply is done using double-wide registers. In other words, `double` is 64 bits, but the `xmm0` register is 128 bits. If you multiply 2 64-bit numbers, the result can *never* exceed 128 bits. But if you multiply *3* 64-bit numbers, as in cubing, the answer could potentially be 192 bits. That’s overflowing the `xmm0` register, so it is necessary to include error-handling code to detect and report that.

*However*…

You can disable proper IEEE 754 behaviour in GCC. Just add the `-ffast-math` flag (in the top right box, just after `-O1`). Now look at what happened. In fact, try replacing the `3` with `4`. Try `10`. Try `1254`. Hell, try `0.5`! See? The compiler knows what’s going on.

For the record, moving those member variables to be local variables… probably also doesn’t make a lick of difference. The compiler probably just does all the computation in registers in any case. You just wrote more code for no reason.

The lesson here is ***TRUST THE COMPILER***. More precisely, don’t assume the compiler is dumb and that you can do better by manually micro-optimizing. The compiler ***WILL*** beat you. Almost every time.

*Sometimes* the compiler might need more information to help it out. All compilers currently have ways to give the compiler this information, but there is not a standard, portable way, yet. There are several proposals in flight, though, like the contracts proposal, and [one specifically about assumptions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1774r4.pdf).

The reason I’m hammering on this is because the fact that you’re finding performance improvements by manually squaring or moving variables around tells me that ***SOMETHING IS WRONG***. I don’t know what you’re doing wrong, but I know that you’re doing *something* wrong. You shouldn’t have to treat the compiler like a dumb tool that has to be outsmarted to get performance. You should be able to cooperate with the compiler—basically, just write good, clear, idiomatic C++ code—and get top-notch performance. It’s 2021 (almost 2022!); if you can get better performance merely by doing silly stuff like manually unrolling loops, moving variables around, or expanding calculations with constants, something is *horribly* wrong.

Before I go further, I want to address a comment by  @IEatBagels, saying that you should be using numerics libraries like Eigen, or GPGPU techniques (as with CUDA). They’re not wrong that you *might* get some performance boosts with a numerics library… and *certainly* will if you offload the program to a number-crunching co-processor (which is essentially what a GPU is). But do you *need* either of those things? No, not really. All modern C++ compilers worth mentioning can already vectorize your code right out of the box, and most have OpenMP or the like built right-in. Frankly, the stuff you’re doing really isn’t complicated enough to warrant a third-party numerics library.

As for using CUDA/OpenCL/Vulkan Compute/whatever… well, yeah, obviously that will make your code run faster, in the same sense that running *any* code on two or more computers rather than one will be faster. (Assuming the data set is large enough to make splitting the work over several processors, assuming the work is splittable, assuming blah blah blah all the other stuff that comes along with heterogeneous computing.) But that’s a whole different world of programming, at least for the time being; standard C++ doesn’t *yet* speak heterogeneous computing (but it’s coming!).

Now, you’ve written your code as a class, where all the functions are member functions. Why? This doesn’t actually make any sense. Think of it from the mathematical/statistics sense: if someone wanted the MAE of a set of predictions, why would they need to first construct a “metrics object” before they can run the calculation they actually need?

```
auto const predictions = calculate_predictions();
auto const observations = make_observations();

// okay, now I want the MAE, so I *should* just be able to do:
auto error = mean_absolute_error(predictions, observations);

// but no, apparently I have to do:
auto metrics = Metrics{};
auto error = metrics.mean_absolute_error(predictions, observations);
```

And why? The `Metrics` object doesn’t serve any purpose. You just need it to call the function. So why not just have the function?

Every one of those member functions (except `square()`, which serves no purpose) should be a free function. You could group them in a namespace if you really wanted to. (You should put *all* of your code in your own namespace, and these functions could be in their own sub-namespace.) But there doesn’t seem to be a need for a class.

In addition, there is a remarkable amount of code duplication in those functions. Every one of the “regression” functions is (with modifications to correct the bugs):

```
template <typename Func1, typename Func2>
auto regression(
    std::vector<double> const& y_true,
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred,
    Func1&& func_1,
    Func2&& func_2)
{
    auto store = 0.0;
    auto size = y_true.size();

    for (auto i = decltype(size){}; i < size ; ++i)
    {
        store += func_1(y_true[i], y_pred[i]);
    }

    return func_2(store / size);
}
```

For example, `root_mean_square_error()` is:

```
auto root_mean_square_error(
    std::vector<double> const& y_true,
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    return regression(
        y_true,
        y_pred,
        [] (auto a, auto b) { return std::pow(a - b, 2); },
        [] (auto r) { return std::sqrt(r); }
    );
}
```

And, because you are worried about performance and such, you can verify with Compiler Explorer that the code I wrote above generates *literally identical* assembly to the code in your version of `root_mean_square_error()` (once I correct the bugs, of course).

The next step worth taking is to generalize. First, instead of hard-coding vectors, you could use `std::span`. That will allow you to use these functions with vectors, C++ arrays, C arrays, and even third-party numeric library array types. While we’re at it, we’ll remove the hard-coded `double` type:

```
template <typename T, typename Func1, typename Func2>
auto regression(
    std::span<T const> y_true,
    std::span<T const> y_pred,
    Func1&& func_1,
    Func2&& func_2)
{
    auto store = T{};

    auto p = y_true.begin();
    auto q = y_pred.begin();
    for (; p != y_true.end(); ++p, ++q)
    {
        store += func_1(*p, *q);
    }

    return func_2(store / y_true.size());
}

// For example:
template <typename T>
auto root_mean_square_error(std::span<T const> y_true, std::span<T const> y_pred)
{
    return regression<T>(
        y_true,
        y_pred,
        [] (auto a, auto b) { return std::pow(a - b, 2); },
        [] (auto r) { return std::sqrt(r); }
    );
}
```

We could go even further, and make the code even more generic. But before we do that, I want to point out that what that `regression()` function is doing is a bog-standard algorithm. In fact, it’s such a common pattern, that there are actually *multiple* algorithms in the standard library that could do it. The old dog would be `std::inner_product()`:

```
template <typename T, typename Func1, typename Func2>
auto regression(
    std::span<T const> y_true,
    std::span<T const> y_pred,
    Func1&& func_1,
    Func2&& func_2)
{
    return func_2(
        std::inner_product(
            y_true.begin(),
            y_true.end(),
            y_pred.begin(),
            T{},
            std::plus<>{},
            std::forward<Func1>(func_1))
        / y_true.size());
}
```

However, `std::transform_reduce()` is the out-of-order, parallelizable version of `std::inner_product()`. In your case, it’s okay to parallelize the algorithm, so you can use `std::transform_reduce()`.

Now, without further comment, I’m just going to show you the way I would write `root_mean_square_error()` using C++20. I’m not saying my way is the “right” way, or the only way. I just want to illustrate a point.

Here’s (basically) your version (with bugs fixed):

```
double root_mean_square_error (
    std::vector<double> const& y_true, 
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    auto const size = y_true.size();

    auto store = 0.0;

    for (auto i = decltype(size){}; i < size ; ++i)
        store += std::pow(y_true[i] - y_pred[i], 2);

    return std::sqrt(store / size) ;
}
```

Here’s my version (just a rough, first pass… later I might properly constrain the detail function, and support sized and non-sized ranges, and so on):

```
namespace detail_ {

template <typename T>
concept not_bool = not std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>, bool>;

template <typename T>
concept arithmetic = std::integral<T> or std::floating_point<T>;

// This is just a basic implementation.
//
// To improve this, I'd constrain the template parameters, and account
// for non-sized ranges and non-default constructible types and so on.
template <typename R1, typename R2, typename F1, typename F2>
auto regression(R1&& y_true, R2&& y_pred, F1&& f1, F2&& f2)
{
    return f2(
        std::transform_reduce(
            std::ranges::begin(y_true),
            std::ranges::end(y_true),
            std::ranges::begin(y_pred),
            std::ranges::range_value_t<R1>{},
            std::plus<>{},
            std::forward<F1>(f1))
        / std::ranges::size(y_true));
}

} // namespace detail_

template <typename T>
concept number = detail_::arithmetic<T> and detail_::not_bool<T>;

template <std::ranges::input_range R1, std::ranges::input_range R2>
    requires number<std::ranges::range_value_t<R1>>
        and std::same_as<
            std::remove_cv_t<std::ranges::range_value_t<R1>>,
            std::remove_cv_t<std::ranges::range_value_t<R2>>>
auto root_mean_square_error_2(R1&& y_true, R2&& y_pred)
    // pre: not std::ranges::empty(y_true)
    // pre: std::ranges::size(y_true) == pre: std::ranges::size(y_pred)
{
    return detail_::regression(
        std::forward<R1>(y_true),
        std::forward<R2>(y_pred),
        [] (auto a, auto b) { return std::pow(a - b, 2); },
        [] (auto r) { return std::sqrt(r); });
}
```

Couple things about my version:

1. It’s a lot longer, but remember that that detail function gets reused for all the regression functions (`mean_absolute_error()`, `mean_gamma_deviance()`, etc.). You only need to test and optimize the one function, and all the regression functions will benefit from it.
2. That means that adding new regression functions is trivial. You want mean squared log error, max error, or whatever else? It’s a one-liner (not counting constraints, of course, but if you wanted to, you could make a single concept with all constraints, and reuse that).
3. It supports any numeric value type, not just `double`: integer types, `float`, `long double`, and even `float16`.
4. It supports any range type, not just `std::vector`: C++ arrays, C arrays, arbitrary third-party numeric library types, and even stream views.

And here’s the kicker. Are you ready for this? All that power, flexibility, and extensibility I gained—not to mention the simplification of testing, optimizing, and extending due to extracting the guts of all the regression functions into a single function—surely must come with a performance cost, right?

Nope. [My version is up to 2× faster](https://quick-bench.com/q/P8oqVMaIfdQyJ8fcin6JrzZwGPU).

*That* is what programming in C++ is all about: writing portable, high-level, reusable, and extensible code… that *still* melts CPUs and beats any other language out there.

So here’s my summary of the high-level design review:

- Mechanically translating Python code to C++ will probably gain you some performance improvements, but *nothing* compared to what you could do if you just started from scratch in C++, writing code based on C++ philosophy, using C++ idioms.
- You have an antagonistic relationship with your compiler, where you’re trying to tweak this and that to get around what you imagine the dumb tool’s limitations are. That kind of thinking made sense in the 1980s, maybe most of the 1990s, and *possibly* the early 2000s. But it doesn’t fly anymore. Modern compilers are so freaking advanced, that even *experts* are frequently gobsmacked by how smart they are at optimizing their code. Instead of trying to undermine, outmanoeuvre, and outsmart the compiler, you need to learn to respect it as a partner in your coding endeavours. You need to learn how to communicate with it—how to tell it what you want in a way it can understand, so it can work its magic to your benefit. Don’t say “the compiler is failing to optimize the code as much as I want, so I need to work around it”, say “what information do I need to give the compiler so it knows what I need it to do”.
- Rather than simply throwing coding constructs at a problem because they’re the proverbial hammer that makes everything look like nails, think about what you’re trying to create on a conceptual level, and implement that in code. For example, if you want to calculate the mean value of a set of data, do you first get/build a “statistics object”, and then use that to do the calculation? No, of course not. You just do the calculation; you just plug the data into the formula, and get an answer out of it. A formula is a function (mathematically speaking and programatically speaking). So you don’t need a class, you just need a function.

  Incidentally, this is the kind of micro-optimization you generally don’t need to worry about, but in point of fact, having your statistics functions be non-static member functions of a class, rather than free functions, makes them less efficient. Member functions take an additional, hidden parameter—`this`—which you pay the price for ever time they’re called. Even if you don’t use it, that hidden `this` also prevents a number of other optimizations; for example, member functions can never be `[[gnu:const]]` (though they can be `[[gnu:pure]]`). This is yet another example of when doing the right thing in C++—in this case, making functions be just functions, without requiring unnecessary classes—automatically gives you better performance.
- “DRY”—“don’t repeat yourself”. All of your functions can be refactored to pull common elements out into reusable detail functions, with no loss of usability or efficiency. Doing so makes everything easier to test and optimize, because the core of *all* the functions is in a single place. You only need to make it perfect once, and *all* of the functions will be better.
- Think big. Rather than just writing functions that solve your immediate problem, step back and consider how you could solve *future* problems as well. Today you want to calculate the F-score of a vector of `double`s. Tomorrow you might need the F-score of a `boost::numeric::ublas::vector_slice<boost::numeric::ublas::vector<long double>>`. It takes virtually the same amount of effort to write the one function with `std::vector<double>` as it does to write a template that takes an arbitrary range (you can always add all the constraints and other concepts bells and whistles later; they’re not strictly necessary).

  Even if you never do end up using the function for anything other than `std::vector<double>`, you can still benefit from the practice of *trying* to generalize your code.

## Code review

Alright, now let’s dig into the actual code. Because the functions are so repetitive, I will mostly be able to review a single function, and the notes will apply to most/all.

Before I get into the code, I have to comment on what’s *missing*.

- There is no namespace. You should always put your code in your own, personal namespace.
- There is a serious lack of comments. You have comments grouping the functions—that’s very good—and comments explaining what `tp` and `fp` stand for—also good. (Though, honestly, I’d normally prefer to write out `true_positive` and `false_positive`. That’s a personal preference, though, and it doesn’t really apply to situations where the short version is the mathematical standard, as it is for `tp` and `fp`.)

  But there are no other comments explaining your reasoning. You don’t need to write useless comments that explain what the code is doing, but you do really need to explain when you are doing something non-obvious. For example, why do you loop over the data twice in `precision()` and `recall()`? Is there a reason? What about in `jaccard_score()`… isn’t `uni` just `size`?

  Note that merely the act of writing the comments—trying to explain your reasoning—forces you to *think* about your reasoning. Had you tried to explain why you were simply counting in the second loop in `jaccard_score()`, you would have realized you got the algorithm wrong. (Actually, you would have realized that [the original code’s documentation is wrong](https://cppsecrets.com/users/575811210512111711510410010510711510410511657575764103109971051084699111109/Python-Scikit-Learn-Jaccard-Score.php).)
- Most egregiously, there is not a single letter documenting the functions’ interfaces, preconditions, or usage. I can deduce from the code that you are not expecting empty vectors (otherwise, you’d be dividing by zero when you do `store / size`). But the only way I could spot that is by doing a detailed scan of the code… which most people are not going to have the time or inclination to do. I can also deduce that the sizes of the two vectors passed to all the functions must be the same. Those are important preconditions that users of your functions really need to know. Are there any other preconditions? For example, is, perhaps, the range of values in the two data sets supposed to be between zero and one?
- Finally, no tests. How do you even know your functions work? (Spoiler: some of them don’t.) Code without tests is garbage code, in the sense that if someone checks in code without tests into a project I’m working on, I will immediately and summarily reject the code with prejudice, and throw the whole commit into the garbage. I won’t even look at it, so it doesn’t matter if it’s the most incredible code ever written by a god-level programmer. If it’s got no tests, it’s worse than useless to me.

  Writing tests for your code should be the *first* thing you do. It forces you to *think* about your interface and usability, so you will automatically write better code. You should use a proper test library, like Catch or Google Test, or Boost.Test, write the tests for your code first, and only *then* start writing your actual functions.

One more thing before we start: all of your functions have very restricted interfaces. They all take `std::vector<double>` and *only* `std::vector<double>`. This is unnecessarily restrictive. It is so easy to write generic code in C++. Let's start with one of your functions:

```
        double mean_absolute_error (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                store += std::abs(y_true[i] - y_pred[i]) ;
                
                }
            
            return store/size ;
                
            }
```

First, we refactor to use iterators rather than indexes. Iterators are not only more generic, they are… theoretically… faster. Why? Well, if you have an index and two arrays/vectors, you need 4 values:

1. the start pointer of the first array
2. the start pointer of the second array
3. the index; and
4. the end index.

And on each loop iteration, you need to do three things:

1. increment the index (`++index`)
2. calculate the pointer for the first array (`start_1 + index`)
3. calculate the pointer for the second array (`start_2 + index`)

But with iterators you only need 3 values:

1. the iterator for the first array
2. the iterator for the second array; and
3. the end iterator.

And on each loop iteration, you only need to do two things:

1. increment the iterator for the first array (`++p_1`)
2. increment the iterator for the second array (`++p_2`)

You see? Iterators are intrinsically more efficient. (In practice, the compiler might be able to optimize an index just as well… or it might simply ignore the index and use iterators internally.)

So, refactoring the code to use iterators:

```
        double mean_absolute_error (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            
            auto p_1 = y_true.begin();
            auto p_2 = y_pred.begin();
            
            auto const q_1 = y_true.end();
            
            for (; p_1 != q_1; ++p_1, ++p_2) {
                
                store += std::abs(*p_1 - *p_2) ;
                
                }
            
            return store / y_true.size() ;
                
            }
```

And to make that completely generic, we just template the argument types, and use generic `begin()`, `end()`, and so on:

```
        template <typename R>
        double mean_absolute_error (
            R const& y_true, 
            R const& y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            
            auto p_1 = std::ranges::begin(y_true);
            auto p_2 = std::ranges::begin(y_pred);
            
            auto const q_1 = std::ranges::end(y_true);
            
            for (; p_1 != q_1; ++p_1, ++p_2) {
                
                store += std::abs(*p_1 - *p_2) ;
                
                }
            
            return store / std::ranges::size(y_true) ;
                
            }
```

That’s all there is to it.

(It would be even simpler if we had `views::zip`, of course:

```
        template <typename R>
        double mean_absolute_error (
            R const& y_true, 
            R const& y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            
            for (auto const [a, b] : std::views::zip(y_true, y_pred))
                store += std::abs(a - b) ;
            
            return store / std::ranges::size(y_true) ;
                
            }
```

But we don’t get `zip` until C++23.)

You could add further improvements from there, like constraining the template parameters, supporting value types other than `double`, and supplying different implementations for ranges that don’t have a constant size. But that’s just gravy. The code above already does everything your current code does, and much, much more, with no loss of efficiency.

Alright, from the top:

```
        double mean_absolute_error (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
```

[The convention in C++ is to put the type modifiers with the type](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout). In plain English:

- `T &t` is C style.
- `T& t` is C++ style.

```
            double store {0} ;
```

It’s good to space out your code a bit when it makes sense, but [there’s a point where it gets ridiculous](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl15-use-spaces-sparingly). There is no purpose to spacing the semicolon away from the statement it terminates; we don’t put spaces between the last letter and the period at the end of sentences. Nor is there any purpose to separating the braced initializer from the variable it’s initializing; `store {0}` makes it look like the `{0}` is unrelated to the `store`. (It’s also inconsistent to write `store {0}` but `y_true[0]`.)

Also, you seem to really like the `type var{init};` form of variable declarations. That’s fine, but it does get a little weird when you *really* go all-in. For example, I’ve been programming C++ since before it was standardized, and I think this is the first time I’ve *ever* seen `for (int i {0}; ...)`. Tradition and convention has it as `for (int i = 0; ...)`. *Modern* convention is moving toward “<s>Almost</s> Always `auto`”, possibly with concept constraints, which would be `for (auto i = 0; ...)`, which is pretty much the same thing. One thing you need to be cautious of if you’re going to stick with the `type var{init};` form is that you should never use `auto` to get type deduction with that form. That’s because `auto var{init};` behaves differently depending on the version of C++, and in more recent versions, will deduce to an initializer list, not the type of `init`. Personally, I’m a big proponent of consistency, and there is only one declaration form that is perfectly consistent, and perfectly behaved in *all* cases: `auto var = init;`, or `auto var = type{init};` to force a type. But the form you like is fine… just don’t use `auto` with it.

```
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
```

There are some insidious bugs lurking here.

First, it’s `std::size_t`, not `size_t`.

Second, the type of `y_true.size()` is *not* (necessarily) `std::size_t`. It’s `std::vector<double>::size_type`. It should be harmless to force that into a `std::size_t`, though. However…

This is not good: `i < size`. This is comparing a signed `int` to an unsigned `std::size_t`. Signed/unsigned comparisons are dangerous; if you compile with warnings turned on (and you should!) you should be getting warnings about this code.

But there’s an even bigger problem. On some platforms, `int` is a *lot* smaller than either `std::size_t` or `std::vector<double>::size_type`… which means you could be getting truncation or wraparound (which would be UB). I believe `int` is only 32 bits on Windows, but `std::size_t` (and probably `std::vector<double>::size_type`) is 64, so this is not a rare problem you will only run into on obscure systems.

This is why you may have noticed I rewrote these lines as:

```
    auto size = y_true.size();

    for (auto i = decltype(size){}; i < size ; ++i)
```

The `auto` here correctly sets the type of `size` to `std::vector<double>::size_type`, and the `decltype(size)` makes sure `i` is the same type.

Even better, though, would be to use iterators. It’s unfortunately a little clunky because we don’t have `std::views::zip_view` until C++23, but it’s still safer, more flexible, and more efficient than indexes.

Even *better*, though, would be to stop and think about what these loops and such are actually doing, identifying the patterns, and using standard library algorithms when appropriate.

I’ll admit this is a little tricky in current C++, because all of the functions are working with two ranges simultaneously. Once we get `views::zip` in C++23, it will become easy. For example, `accuracy()` is:

```
auto accuracy(
    std::vector<double> const& y_true,
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    return -(double{
        std::ranges::count_if(
            std::views::zip(y_true, y_pred),
            [] (auto&& p) { return std::get<0>(p) == std::get<1>(p); })}
        / y_true.size());
}
```

That’s just “zip the elements of `y_true` and `y_pred` together, then count the ones that are equal” (and convert to `double` and divide by the size for the final answer, of course).

But even today, you can still do this with `std::inner_product()` or `std::transform_reduce()`… easy to spot, because there are very few algorithms that take two ranges, and even fewer that take two ranges *and* produce a single value (rather than another range). These functions are a bit more verbose because they don’t support ranges, but:

```
auto accuracy(
    std::vector<double> const& y_true,
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    return -(double{
        std::transform_reduce(
            std::ranges::begin(y_true),
            std::ranges::end(y_true),
            std::ranges::begin(y_pred),
            std::plus<>{},
            [] (auto&& a, auto&& b) { return a == b ? std::size_t{1} : std::size_t{0}; })}
        / y_true.size());
}

// or:

auto accuracy(
    std::vector<double> const& y_true,
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    return -(double{
        std::inner_product(
            std::ranges::begin(y_true),
            std::ranges::end(y_true),
            std::ranges::begin(y_pred),
            std::size_t{0},
            std::plus<>{},
            [] (auto&& a, auto&& b) { return a == b ? std::size_t{1} : std::size_t{0}; })}
        / y_true.size());
}
```

`std::transform_reduce()` is better than `std::inner_product()`, though, because `std::inner_product()` *must* be done in order, while `std::transform_reduce()` can be done out-of-order, and even parallelized, which can be faster.

And as I illustrated above, using standard algorithms can be *much* faster than hand-rolling your own loops, and that’s even before you start using things like `std::execution::par_unseq`.

```
store += 2.0 * ((y_true[i]*std::log(y_true[i]/y_pred[i])) + (y_pred[i]-y_true[i])) ;
```

There’s some really odd spacing going on there. I don’t get the logic of putting a space between the semicolon and the rest of the statement, but not a single space in `(y_true[i]*std::log(y_true[i]/y_pred[i]))`. I don’t see how that improves readability.

Also, you’re not defending against `y_pred[i]` being zero. Same goes elsewhere where you divide by `y_true[i]`. And, of course, you never account for empty data sets where the size is zero.

```
        double accuracy (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double store {0} ;
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i]){
                    
                    store += 1.0 ;
                    
                    }
                
                }
            
            return -(store / size) ;
                
            }
```

All of your classification functions are essentially counting. In this case, you’re counting the number of times in the data set when the true and predicted values match.

The problem is: you’re using a `double` to count. Yes, you *ultimately* want a `double`, so you can do the division and not get truncation. But for the actual counting, doing `store += 1.0` on most hardware will be *significantly* slower than doing `++store` (assuming `store` is an integer). On most hardware, you will get a *dramatic* performance boost if you do:

```
double accuracy (
    std::vector<double> const& y_true, 
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    auto store = std::size_t{0};

    auto const size = y_true.size();
    for (auto i = decltype(store){0}; i < size ; ++i)
    {
        if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i])
            ++store;
    }

    return -(double{store} / size);
}
```

This is even more true for `precision()` and `recall()`, where you’re incrementing *two* `double`s, in *two* loops:

```
double precision (
    std::vector<double> const& y_true, 
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    auto tp = std::size_t{0}; // true positive
    auto fp = std::size_t{0}; // false positive

    auto const size = y_true.size();
    for (auto i = decltype(store){0}; i < size ; ++i)
    {
        if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i] and y_pred[i] == 1)
            ++tp;

        if (y_true[i] != y_pred[i] and y_pred[i] == 1)
            ++fp;
    }

    return tp / double{tp + fp};
}
```

(Your compiler is probably smart enough to merge the two loops on its own. Still, it doesn’t really make sense to write two loops when you really only need one.)

Before I move on, I need to comment about all the times you’re using `==` and `!=` with `double`s. That is almost always wrong. It is almost impossible to get *exactly* the same result from a set of mathematical operations if they’re not done in the *exact* same order. Also, if you’re dealing at all with any sort of analog input (like a sensor), line noise alone will screw up two readings that are supposed to be exactly the same.

Comparing floating point numbers is a dark art. If I even *start* to explain it here, we’ll be here all day. But the bottom line is that you should give the user a way to specify a comparison function. You could always provide a sensible default for simplicity. For example:

```
template <std::floating_point T>
constexpr auto numeric_compare(T a, T b, T max_relative_error) noexcept
    // pre: not std::isnan(max_relative_error)
{
    if (std::isunordered(a, b))
        return std::partial_ordering::unordered;

    if (std::abs(a - b) <= (std::max(std::abs(a), std::abs(b)) * max_relative_error))
        return std::partial_ordering::equivalent;

    return (a < b) ? std::partial_ordering::less : std::partial_ordering::greater;
}

template <std::floating_point T>
constexpr auto numeric_compare(T a, T b) noexcept
{
    return numeric_compare(a, b, std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon());
}

template <std::integer T>
constexpr auto numeric_compare(T a, T b) noexcept
{
    return a <=> b;
}

template <typename NumericCompare>
double accuracy (
    std::vector<double> const& y_true, 
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred,
    NumericCompare&& compare)
{
    auto store = std::size_t{0};

    auto const size = y_true.size();
    for (auto i = decltype(store){0}; i < size ; ++i)
    {
        if (compare(y_true[i], y_pred[i]) == 0)
            ++store;
    }

    return -(double{store} / size);
}

double accuracy (
    std::vector<double> const& y_true, 
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    return accuracy(y_true, y_pred,
        [] (auto a, auto b) { return numeric_compare(a, b); });
}
```

Then if I want, say, 6 digits of precision, I can do:

```
auto acc = accuracy(y_true, y_pred, [] (auto a, auto b) { return numeric_compare(a, b, 0.000001); });

// or:
auto my_compare = [] (auto a, auto b) { return numeric_compare(a, b, 0.000001); };
auto acc = accuracy(y_true, y_pred, my_compare);
```

One more note about comparisons:

```
        double precision (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred
        ) {
            
            double tp {0} ; // true positive
            double fp {0} ; // false positive
            
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i] == 1) {  // <--
```

That last line is wrong. Python allows chaining comparisons, so `a == b == c` gets rewriten as `a == b and b == c`. C++ does not support that. So `y_true[i] == y_pred[i] == 1` is interpreted as `(y_true[i] == y_pred[i]) == 1`. Which reduces to either `true == 1` or `false == 1`… which is just `true` or `false`. In other words, that whole expression is basically just `y_true[i] == y_pred[i]`. To mimic the Python behaviour, you want `y_true[i] == y_pred[i] and y_pred[i] == 1`. (Python needs chained operators because it does not have an optimizing compiler, so if you write `y_true[i] == y_pred[i] and y_pred[i] == 1`, `y_pred[i]` gets evaluated twice. C++ expects the compiler to optimize the repeated evaluation (presuming it has no side effects, of course).)

```
        double jaccard_score (
            const std::vector<double> &y_true, 
            const std::vector<double> &y_pred) {
            
            double intersect {0} ;
            double uni {0} ;
            
            size_t size {y_true.size()} ;
            
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i]) {
                    
                    intersect += 1.0 ;
                    
                    }
                }
            
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                    uni += 1.0 ;
                    
                }
            
            return intersect / uni ;
                
                    }
```

I believe this function is incorrect. (Did you test your code? If you’d written proper tests, and applied them, you would have discovered this.)

As far as I understand it, the Jaccard index is `| y_true ∩ y_pred | ÷ | y_true ∪ y_pred |`. In other words, the size of the intersection divided by the size of the union. `uni` is not the size of the union, it’s just the size of the set. That loop:

```
            for (int i {0}; i < size ; ++ i) {
                
                    uni += 1.0 ;
                    
                }
```

is just `uni = double{size};`, calculated the long way around.

You can calculate the size of the union as the size of both sets minus the size of the intersection… and you’ve already got the size of the intersection. So you could do:

```
auto jaccard_score (
    std::vector<double> const& y_true, 
    std::vector<double> const& y_pred)
{
    auto const set_size = y_true.size();

    auto intersection_size = std::size_t{0};
    for (auto i = decltype(set_size){0}; i < set_size; ++i)
    {
        if (y_true[i] == y_pred[i]) // should do a proper comparison here
            ++intersection_size;
    }

    return double{intersection_size} / ((2 * set_size) - intersection_size);
}
```

Finally:

```
} met ;
```

Why?

Summary of code review:

- There are no comments at all, which means:

  1. No explanations of usage, so there’s no way to decide whether there might be better ways of accomplishing something.
  2. No precondition expectations, so there’s no way to know whether an unconsidered corner case is a bug or not.
  3. No postcondition promises, so there’s no way for a user of the code to know what state it might leave their program in.
  4. No explanations of rationale for any of the code, so there’s no way to know if something done in the code was done for very smart reasons, or was just a brain fart.
- There are no tests at all. Untested code is garbage code, not even worthy of review in a serious project.
- The usage of whitespace is… idiosyncratic, to say the least, and quite excessive. By my estimate, over half the lines of your code are just blank lines. Indenting is also excessive, and inconsistent: you indent the class access specifier (`public:`) by four spaces… and then indent the functions by *another* four spaces, except for `square()`. That’s 10% of the horizontal space in an 80 line text editor just wasted. There are spaces before semicolons, but not around binary operators… both of which hurt readability.
- These functions should all be free functions; the `Metrics` class serves no purpose. There should be a namespace, though.
- There is a massive amount of repetition. A refactor pulling out common code would make your functions simpler, easier to test, and easier to optimize (because you’d only need to test/optimize in one place).
- Hand-rolled loops are a code smell. Use algorithms. Not only do they make your code easier to understand, they can also offer performance benefits.
- Watch out for truncation and signed/unsigned comparisons. These are a common problem with hand-rolled loops. (Better yet, don’t write hand-rolled loops, or, if you must, use iterators, which are more flexible, and (theoretically) faster.)
- Don’t compare floating point numbers with `==`.
- Make your interfaces more generic. It’s not that much harder to support completely generic interfaces than it is to restrict it to `std::vector<double>`, and there is no performance cost.